# How can I get full speed internet/Ethernet access to all rooms of my apartment

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, cable

I have a 4 bedroom apartment and every person in those 4 bedrooms has multiple devices they want to hardwire such as desktops, Xbox, PlayStation, and laptops. Each person has 2-3 devices they want hardwired. I currently have Ethernet cables absolutely everywhere and the connection has been not so good probably because so many people are on it. I’m going to call my internet provider and have the internet increased from 1.5Gbps to 3Gbps. I’m hoping this may help with some of the connection issues, but my main question is how can I get multiple Ethernet ports from the living room to each individual room without using the Ethernet cables and extra routers that I’m currently using. It looks messy and I know these old routers can’t pick up 3Gbps internet so we’re not getting what we would be paying for for the devices we want hardwired.

Whatever I do cannot damage or affect the home, as I do not own it as well.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you have Ethernet going through walls to bedrooms, at least? What kind of speed do you expect _per person_ – given that there are four people sharing the connection, will 1Gbps per user be enough?

Comment: No Ethernet connections going through walls, or at least I don’t have the ports like previous homes I’ve had. And I’d like to get as close to 3Gbps as possible in each room.

Comment: What's your CPE/Modem look like - there's no 'real' standard I know that does 3 gigs on its own - most common ethernet is 1, 2.5, 5 and 10 , and most wifi isn't going to get anywhere near the performance you want. You're probably looking at one line per room, and multigig switches to get the perfomance you want

Comment: Also depending, fiber's a lot skinner, so that might be an option for easily conceilable, if somewhat fragile cabling

Comment: It sounds like the major issue is likely your modem/router.   I'd do 2 things -    (1)   I'd put all the ethernet ports onto a switch, and then plug the switch into the LAN port of the router.  Many SOHO routers do switching in software which is slow.   The second thing I'd do is either build a router from a PC or get something which can handle your connection.

Comment: Getting 3 gigabits per room is not going to be cheap - and may not be possible with your existing cabling.  That said, do you actually know what kind of speed you need, or are you just assuming you need more speed?  It would seem somewhat unlikely your devices would need more then gigabit based on the very generic usage statement above.

Comment: You should only use 1 router, but in each room you should consider adding a gigabit ethernet switch so all the devices in that room can plug into that.  (Again, a router is slow, adds complexity and routing issues, while a typical switch is cheap and fast because it just forwards packets in hardware.)

Comment: Okay I did not know that. I have my main modem which is Bell Fibre with 3Gbps download and upload speed as of tomorrow once it’s upgraded and I have 2 routers connected to that modem. I guess the switches would be better and should replace the routers?

Comment: If you look at 24 port switches you can find one with 20-24 gigabit port plus a uplink 10gig port.  Thus connecting your internet to the 10gig port.  Thus, no single port can go over 1 gigabit but they can go up to 3gigabit combined.

Comment: Unless your modem is a modem/router (which may well be the case) you do need 1 router - at a minimum to provide DHCP (ie giving IP addresses to devices) and handle NAT for your network.  You may also need something to handle WIFI?    You may want to update your post with the models of hardware you have so people can provide more specific help.    (Also, are you sure your Bell Fibre device is a modem - that makes no sense.   Did you mean an ONT?